# Can access clusterip service from within cluster but not by using kubectl proxy

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, kubernetes-service

I am trying to access a clusterip service (running kubernetes on my laptop through docker-for-mac).

Following the [instructions here](https://hackernoon.com/getting-started-with-microservices-and-kubernetes-76354312b556), I was able to successfully ping the service like this:

```
kubectl run curl --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl -i --tty
curl -v http://10.106.1.204:8000/api/v0.1/predictions -d '{"foo": "bar"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

but I can't get it to work using the service name instead of it's ip. I then tried to use kubectl proxy [as described here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-nodeport-vs-loadbalancer-vs-ingress-when-should-i-use-what-922f010849e0), but I can't get it to work:

```
kubectl proxy --port=8080 &
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/deploy-test/services/10.106.1.204:8000/api/v0.1/predictions
```

that gives me a 404 error as do all of the following:

```
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/deploy-test/services/10.106.1.204:8000
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/deploy-test/services/10.106.1.204:8000/predictions
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/deploy-test/services/10.106.1.204:8000/api/v0.1/predictions
```

as well as all combinations of replacing `8000` with `http` in all of the above and/or the ip with the service name.

I can confirm that the proxy is working as `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces/deploy-test/pods` works.

This is the description of the service. Note that I am specifically trying to access it via the clusterip and not use Ambassador.

```
kubectl describe svc -n deploy-test template-product-app-seldon-prediction-service
Name:              template-product-app-seldon-prediction-service
Namespace:         deploy-test
Labels:            seldon-app=template-product-app-seldon-prediction-service
                   seldon-deployment-id=template-product-app-seldon-prediction-service
Annotations:       getambassador.io/config:
                     ---
                     apiVersion: ambassador/v1
                     kind: Mapping
                     name: seldon_deploy-test_seldon-prediction-service_rest_mapping
                     prefix: /seldon/deploy-test/seldon-prediction-service/
                     service: template-product-app-seldon-prediction-service.deploy-test:8000
                     timeout_ms: 3000
                     ---
                     apiVersion: ambassador/v1
                     kind: Mapping
                     name: seldon_deploy-test_seldon-prediction-service_grpc_mapping
                     grpc: true
                     prefix: /seldon.protos.Seldon/
                     rewrite: /seldon.protos.Seldon/
                     service: template-product-app-seldon-prediction-service.deploy-test:5001
                     timeout_ms: 3000
                     headers:
                       namespace: deploy-test
                       seldon: seldon-prediction-service
                     retry_policy:
                       retry_on: connect-failure
                       num_retries: 3
Selector:          seldon-app=template-product-app-seldon-prediction-service
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.106.1.204
Port:              http  8000/TCP
TargetPort:        8000/TCP
Endpoints:         10.1.1.4:8000
Port:              grpc  5001/TCP
TargetPort:        5001/TCP
Endpoints:         10.1.1.4:5001
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Any suggestions on how to do this via `kubectl proxy` instead of spinning up a pod with `radial/busyboxplus:curl`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general format to access http services through the kubectl proxy is the following:

```
http://api.host/api/v1/namespaces/NAMESPACE/services/SERVICE_NAME:SERVICE_PORT/proxy/
```

In your case you added the cluster ip which is not necessary. 
Try:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces/deploy-test/services/template-product-app-seldon-prediction-service:8000/proxy/api/v0.1/predictions
```

http://127.0.0.1:43029/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard

Note that this will probably not work with grpc, only for http. (Use a NodePort oder LoadBalancer instead in that case)

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried that. That's what I meant by "as well as all combinations of replacing 8000 with http in all of the above and/or the ip with the service name". Apologies if that was unclear. By service name I meant `template-product-app-seldon-prediction-service`. I'm only trying `http`, not worried about `grpc`. Any idea why the command you've posted would also give a 404?

Comment: Oh I see you left off `/proxy/`. Just tried that as well, still a 404 :(

Comment: I suspect the 404 is originating from your application, not the kubernetes api proxy. Have you tried to add the request path `api/v0.1/predictions` accordingly? (I edited my answer accordingly)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have tried that (see the final option in my OP) and unfortunately it also gives a 404. I don't think it's the application as it gives me the correct response from within the cluster and also via ambassador. Could it be due to a proxy setting on my laptop maybe?

Comment: In your final option you don’t use the service name in the url but the Cluster ip which won’t work. You should try without proxy settings just in case too.

Comment: apologies if I've been unclear. I have tried all the options I posted with botht he ip address as well as the service name, and both the port and the port name (which I think is http, but not 100% sure about that) and all combinations of the above.

Comment: `curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces/deploy-test/services/template-product-app-seldon-prediction-service` returns the service's manifest as json btw, so the problem seems to be the port

Comment: Sorry I mixed up the position of the /proxy/ and updated the URL. (the /proxy/ must be at the end). Tested with a small service in minikube, this time it really should work out!

Comment: That solved it! Thanks so much. Do you have a link to a reference explaining this by any chance? How did you know to put `/proxy/` at the end?

Comment: Ah ok I see it here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#manually-constructing-apiserver-proxy-urls

Comment: Glad it worked out - I did not lookup the documentation but used my history file... that lead to the confusion of the path since I had a special setup once. Sorry that it was a little try and error.